# Does the HERE Fleet Telematics API give you extra information if you're on premium?

Tags: here-api

I'm looking to use the lane information from the fleet telematics api to understand what lanes does a specific road have (for example, knowing if a road has a right turn lane). I'm currently querying the LANE_FC tiles for this information. This works, but a lot of the time it seems to return no results for links that do have turning lanes. I noticed that LANE_FC is in "PDE-Premium-Road-Info", so I'm wondering if I need to upgrade to premium to get better lane information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general a Freemim plan would have access to all PDE layers. The lane data is usually only available for Major roads like Motorways and also may depend on the region hence if LANE_FC is not returning any data for a tile then most probably there is no data in that tile.